# Swing JPanel not shown

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a very simple java swing application, I have a canvas class extended from JPanel

```
public class Canvas extends JPanel 
{

private void doDrawing(Graphics g) 
{

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawString("Java 2D", 50, 50);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{

    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}
}
```

And then I have my main class

```
public class SwingCounter extends JFrame {
   private JTextField tfCount;  // Use Swing's JTextField instead of AWT's TextField
   private int count = 0;


   public SwingCounter () {
      Container cp = getContentPane();
      cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      cp.add(new JLabel("Counter"));
      tfCount = new JTextField("0", 10);
      tfCount.setEditable(false);
      cp.add(tfCount);

      JButton btnCount = new JButton("Count");
      cp.add(btnCount);

      Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
      canvas.setSize(150, 150);
      cp.add(canvas);


      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  // Exit program if close-window button clicked
      setTitle("Swing Counter"); // "this" JFrame sets title
      setSize(300, 100);         // "this" JFrame sets initial size
      setVisible(true);          // "this" JFrame shows
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            new SwingCounter(); // Let the constructor do the job
         }
      });
   }
}
```

It is basically code from a tutorial, apart from the JPanel. Everything shows fine, the JPanel/Canvas doesn't. What is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding your Canvas class to a panel which uses a `FlowLayout`. The FlowLayout respects the preferred size of all components. Your component has a `preferred size of (0, 0)` so there is nothing to paint.

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your Canvas class to return an appropriate `Dimension` for your panel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and a working example that does implement the getPreferredSize() method.

Also, don't call your class Canvas, since that is already an AWT component and is confusing. Use a more descriptive name.